# How can I return JSON error in format.csv in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an endpoint that accepts .csv for exporting. However, I want to also return a JSON error if a condition is met when this export endpoint is hit.

A snippet of the code I'm trying to make work

```rb
format.csv do
  if @products.exists?(payment: nil)
    render json: { success: false, message: 'Some products are missing payments' } 
  end

  # Export to CSV
end
```

However this doesn't seem to work, instead it still returns export of an empty CSV.

I also tried something like this:

```rb
format.csv do
  if @products.exists?(payment: nil)
    format.json do
      render json: { success: false, message: 'Some products are missing payments' }
    end
  end

  # Export to CSV
end
```

and

```rb
format.csv do
  if @products.exists?(payment: nil)
    format.json do
      render json: { success: false, message: 'Some products are missing payments' }
    end
  else
    # Export to CSV
  end
end
```

But it still doesn't work, with the latter returning 204 no content.

If anyone knows how this can be done, help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Nesting `format` blocks does not really make sense because the server can only return a CSV or a JSON response. And depending on what content type the browser requested, Rails will either go into the `format.csv` or the `format.json` block.

Comment: @spickermann how do I handle checks/errors before exporting then?

Comment: What about checking preconditions before even rendering the link to the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all you have to do is specify the `content_type` when rendering JSON and you can use this to conditionally apply the correct logic on the front end.

So my final code looks like so:

```rb
format.csv do
  if @products.exists?(payment: nil)
    render json: { success: false, message: 'Some products are missing payments' }, status: :bad_request, content_type: 'application/json'
  else
    # Export to CSV
  end
end
```